# Discord Python Bot: Leveling Up System

Tags: python, bots, discord

So I've googled a few different searches and I've watched this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pKkrCHnun0M about making a level system for my bot. Basically, the bot (IN PYTHON) is like an adventure tank game; the game gives you a tank to start, allows you to select a map, moving to different sectors of the map, and will use rng to decide if there's an enemy tank. Each destroyed enemy tank gives you 10 xp points. Now, in the video aforementioned, to add xp, he uses messages, and also begins a player's statistic profile upon their entrance to the server.

Now, I want my user to begin his profile upon the entering of the command '&stats'. In the video, he uses json. I have never used json before, so naturally I was confused, but I followed the video's guidance.

I get this error:

```html
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):  File "/home/runner/.local/share/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.
7/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 270, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 72, in on_message
    await level_up(users, author, message.channel)  File "main.py", line 435, in level_up
    lvl_end = float('experience ** 1/2')
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'experience ** 1/2'
```

Upon entering any message on my testing server. But alas, I fear it is unimportant. 
I'm building this bot in repl.it, I should mention at this point,
So I want to figure out how I can start the json file upon a command, and I also want to add xp to a player's profile (and Kill amount but that doesn't matter too much) by the destruction of enemies. And I need the levels as well. Currently my code for all this stuff is

```html
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
    users = json.load(f)

    await update_data(users, member)



  with open("users.json", 'w') as f:
    json.dump(users, f)
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  author = message.author

  with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
    users = json.load(f)

    await update_data(users, author)
    await add_experience(users, author, 5)
    await level_up(users, author, message.channel)
  with open("users.json", 'w') as f:
    json.dump(users, f)


  if message.content.startswith("&stats"):
    global Pxp
    global KA
    Pxp = 0
    KA = 0
    await message.channel.send("XP: " + str(Pxp) + ". Enemy Tanks Killed: " + str(KA) + ".")
  if message.content.startswith('&start'):
    await message.channel.send('Choose vehicle: VT-4, M1 Abrams, T-18 Armata. 1, 2, 3.')
```

and at the bottom,

```html
async def update_data(users, user):
  if not user.id in users:
    users[user.id] = {}
    users[user.id]['experience'] = 0
    users[user.id]['level'] = 1
async def add_experience(users, user, exp):
  users[user.id]['experience'] += exp

async def level_up(users, user, channel):
  experience = users[user.id]['experience']
  lvl_start = users[user.id]['level']
  lvl_end = float('experience ** 1/2')

  if level_start < lvl_end:
    await message.channel.send('{} leveled up to level {}'.format(user.mention, lvl_end))
    users[user.id]['level'] = lvl_end
```

Note that the last snippet generates the previously posted error.

This is also my first post and I didn't know how specific I should be, please be nice :^) I'm sorry that it's so long, and if it's all wrong, just tell me.

Any help is appreciated. If you want to see more code, just ask.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried my best, and I've made a level system! It's server specific and shows the amount of xp you need to gain to get to the next level.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if not message.author.bot:
        print('function load')
        with open('level.json','r') as f:
            users = json.load(f)
            print('file load')
        await update_data(users, message.author,message.guild)
        await add_experience(users, message.author, 4, message.guild)
        await level_up(users, message.author,message.channel, message.guild)

        with open('level.json','w') as f:
            json.dump(users, f)
    await client.process_commands(message)




async def update_data(users, user,server):
    if not str(server.id) in users:
        users[str(server.id)] = {}
        if not str(user.id) in users[str(server.id)]:
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)] = {}
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['experience'] = 0
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['level'] = 1
    elif not str(user.id) in users[str(server.id)]:
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)] = {}
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['experience'] = 0
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['level'] = 1

async def add_experience(users, user, exp, server):
  users[str(user.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['experience'] += exp

async def level_up(users, user, channel, server):
  experience = users[str(user.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['experience']
  lvl_start = users[str(user.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['level']
  lvl_end = int(experience ** (1/4))
  
  if lvl_start < lvl_end:
      await channel.send('{} has leveled up to Level {}'.format(user.mention, lvl_end))
      users[str(user.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['level'] = lvl_end


@client.command(aliases = ['rank','lvl'])
async def level(ctx,member: discord.Member = None):

    if not member:
        user = ctx.message.author
        with open('level.json','r') as f:
        users = json.load(f)
        lvl = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['level']
        exp = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['experience']

        embed = discord.Embed(title = 'Level {}'.format(lvl), description = f"{exp} XP " ,color = discord.Color.green())
        embed.set_author(name = ctx.author, icon_url = ctx.author.avatar_url)
        await ctx.send(embed = embed)
    else:
      with open('level.json','r') as f:
          users = json.load(f)
      lvl = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(member.id)]['level']
      exp = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(member.id)]['experience']
      embed = discord.Embed(title = 'Level {}'.format(lvl), description = f"{exp} XP" ,color = discord.Color.green())
      embed.set_author(name = member, icon_url = member.avatar_url)

      await ctx.send(embed = embed)
```